# Highlighting <td> column depending on value and row. Change existing jQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

The table that will populate depending on the selected dropdown element. There is an HTML code (I didn’t insert a line with dropdown and image)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="PlaneTable" class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20%">Max speed</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">450</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">487</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">450</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">600</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20%">Max speed</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">580</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">490</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">543</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">742</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20%">Climb</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">52</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">34</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">23</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">43</td>
  </tr>
</table 

<!-- And script what set green color to best value and red color to worse -->

<script>
  $("#PlaneTable tbody tr").each(function() {
    var values = [];
    var tds = $(this).find('td');
    tds.each(function() {
      if ($.isNumeric($(this).text())) {
        values.push($(this).text());
      }
    });
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, values);
    var max = Math.max.apply(Math,
      values);
    tds.each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() == min) {
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
      }
      if ($(this).text() == max) {
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'green');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Finally i have this
[image]

I need to change my script for the next requirements:

1. Some data, for example, "Climb" row better if it has a lower value. IMHO better apply a script to row, not to the table. Also, some rows should not be highlighting.
2. If I add a label "km/h". For example 450 km/h highlighting don't work. Need to fix
3. If `<td>` have concrete value "null" (int nullable type), it should not be highlighting anytime

Comment: Looks like a class project. What have you tried so far? Whats not working? Any errors?

Comment: I write the backend in ASP.Net, but with the frontend, I have a problem. 
My code added above. It shows what I tried on, and the issues I want to solve. I'm just learning the jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function getNum(s) {
    var n = false;
    if (s.length) {
      n = parseInt(s, 10);
    }
    return n;
  }

  function getRowData(t) {
    var r = [],
      n;
    $("td", t).each(function(i, el) {
      n = getNum($(el).text());
      if (i > 0 && n) {
        r.push(n);
      }
    });
    return r;
  }

  $("#PlaneTable tbody tr").each(function(ind, row) {
    var values = getRowData($(row));
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, values);
    var max = Math.max.apply(Math, values);
    console.log(values, min, max);
    if ($("td", row).eq(0).text() == "Climb") {
      $(row).addClass("low");
    } else {
      $(row).addClass("high");
    }
    $("td", row).each(function(j, cell) {
      if ($(cell).text().indexOf(min) == 0 && $(".min", row).length < 1) {
        $(this).addClass("min");
      }
      if ($(cell).text().indexOf(max) == 0 && $(".max", row).length < 1) {
        $(cell).addClass("max");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.high .min {
  background-color: red;
}

.high .max {
  background-color: green;
}

.low .min {
  background-color: green;
}

.low .max {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="PlaneTable" class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20%">Max speed</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">450 km/h</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">487 km/h</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">450 km/h</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">600 km/h</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20%">Max speed</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">580 km/h</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">490 km/h</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">543 km/h</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">742 km/h</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 20%">Climb</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">52 km/h</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">34 km/h</td>
    <td style="width: 15%">23 km/h</td>
    <td style="width: 15%"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

References:

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp
- https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Thanks. It solves issue #2. But if I have empty <td>, all row not highlighting (#3 issue)

Comment: thanks. But how i can highlight specific row for rule "low is better"? Some data, for example, "Climb" row better if it has a lower value

Comment: @BogdanIlkiv that is sort of ambiguous. What qualifies as "low"? Do you want to highlight the lower values in "Climb" with a more positive color, say green, to indicate the lower color is preferred?

Comment: http://i.piccy.info/i9/ffbfc2572b087e6527999983633b4a12/1584042489/91453/1367161/Zn_1110_mok_ekrana_870_.png
works good, but if I have an equal value something wrong

Comment: i have on mind, when i choose similar plane with similar speed value, highlighting only one of them. Not two

Comment: @BogdanIlkiv the answer I provided meets all the criteria you outlined in your Post. At this point, you should make a Flow Chart or State Chart to indicate what the result should look like and how you want to reach that goal. You may consider marking and answer to this question, working on the issue further, and then posting another question if you encounter a new issue.